# Is it possible to downgrade ipykernel to 4.10.0 without downgrading to Spyder 3?

Tags: r, python, anaconda, spyder

I am having some trouble with the Spyder IPython kernel crashing when I use the Tkinter backend. According to [this bug report](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/issues/370), it is a problem with the latest version of ipykernel. Additionally, when I use the qt5 backend it is very slow -- this is also a problem with version 5 of the ipykernel (I checked by downgrading ipykernel and using spyder 3, then updating ipykernel again and reproducing the behavior).

I would like to downgrade the ipykernel package to version 4.10.0 without downgrading from Spyder 4 to Spyder 3. Is this possible? When I use the conda command `conda install ipykernel=4.10.0` it wants to automatically downgrade Spyder, but I wonder if there is a workaround.

Comment: Probably going to be difficult if at all possible. If an older version is not maintained as a separate branch (ipykernel=4.10.0 is not), it is best to assume it is a legacy version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really an answer to the original question, but I created a bug report [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/13423), and it was discovered that the bug with qt4 and qt5 rendering matplotlib plots is specific to `ipykernel version 5.3.3`. To fix that particular problem, you only need to downgrade to version 5.3.2 using the command `conda install ipykernel=5.3.2` which is compatible with IPython 4.

Additionally, it looks like a patch has been added to the Tkinter bug (see link in original question) that any user can add themselves. It appears that all of this should be fixed once `ipykernel 5.3.4` gets added to the default conda channel.